# Add two matrices with recursion

Tags: recursion, matrix

In my programming course, we were given to add two matrices together with recursion only. Apparently our professor intended us to make a recursive method but still use one "for" loop to solve it.
However, I'm still convinced that everything that can be done with a for loop can be done with recursion. So I was trying to do it:

The method should look like this:

```
public static int[][] addMatrix(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2)
```

no additional variables may be passed with.

I'm having a real hard time trying to solve this, since this is a very easy exercise using for loop - I thought it was pretty doable with recursion.

Any help ?

--UPDATE

So far my course of thought was like this:
To always take the first matrix with its full size, and step by step breaking the second matrix by taking matrix2[matrix2.length] and calling the method on it, that way I would know where to store the values calculated by the method without using an index variable.
Illustration:

```
X   X     Y   Y
X   X     Y   Y
X   X     Y   Y
```

X are the variables in martix1, Y for matrix2

```
X   X
X   X
X   X     Y  Y
```

Take the last "row":

```
X   X
X   X
X   X     Y
```

And if matrix2 is only 1x1, add it to the appropriate index in matrix1.

This is the best that I could have come up with.

Comment: What is *add two matrices*? `C[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j]`?

Comment: Yes, two dimensional array that every array inside it have the same length (just like a matrix)

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far

Comment: Your condition "no additional variables may be passed" is too restrictive. Is there a particular reason for it? This is fairly easy to solve if you allow for more parameters in the recursive function, and that is how this type of problem is usually solved. Anything with a for loop can be done with recursion, but that proof does not hold if you restrict the number of variables recursion can work with. Of course, you could make matrix2 bigger and hide your helper variables in the additional rows, but that is very inelegant.

Comment: I know it's too restrictive, that's why when I went to my professor he said he intended us to use a for loop inside, not additional variables... is this even possible with the given method ?

Comment: Storing the indexes in global variables? I know it isn't elegant, but it's for hw. And you don't really get to deal with such conditions in real life.

Comment: Sure, by 'cheating'. E.g. make matrix2 bigger, then use the extra rows und columns as your additional variables.

Answer (score 0):

With "matrix2[matrix2.length]" you'd be going out of range by the way since indexes start from 0.

Here is some pseudo code in no particular language that will give you the idea:

```
function addMatrices(mat1, mat2, result_mat /*pass by reference*/, i=0, j=0){
    if (j >= mat1[0].size)
        return result_mat;
    result_mat[i][j] = mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j];
    i ++;
    if (i == mat1.size){
        i = 0;
        j ++;
    }
    return addMatrices(mat1, mat2, result_mat, i, j);
}
```

Comment: I think OP mentioned, no additional variables may be passed with.

Comment: Hm, you're right. But there are many workarounds to do this that I doubt it would be an issue. Storing the indexes in global variables or members of a custom matrix class to name a few.